# setValues, Google Spreadsheet Script error

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm trying to copy a range that consistently changes and add it to the bottom of another sheet.  I'm using the below script with a trigger on sheet1 so it automatically updates.

I'm getting the error

```
Incorrect range height, was 1 but should be 5 (line 10, file "Code")Dismiss
```

The code is below

```
  function storeValue() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');  
  var values = sheet.getSheetValues(3, 1, 3, 6);

  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2'); 
  var row = sheet2.getLastRow();   

  sheet2.insertRowAfter(row)
  sheet2.getRange(row+1,1,3,6).setValues([values]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
sheet2.getRange(row+1,1,3,6).setValues([values]);
```

to

```
sheet2.getRange(row+1,1,3,6).setValues(values);
```

The variable `values` is a double array such as `[[1,2], [3,4]]`. By writing `[values]` you create a three-dimensional array `[[[1,2], [3,4]]]` which is not what `setValues` expects.